# Can I delete package-lock.json when switching to pnpm?

Tags: npm, package-lock.json, pnpm

I'm in the process of switching from `npm` to `pnpm`, which has a different set of features that I prefer.

The former uses `package-lock.json` to lock exact packages versions, the latter `pnpm-lock.yaml`.

According to the [docs](https://pnpm.js.org/en/limitations), `pnpm` ignores `package-lock.json`, which seems to become redundant. And, as a consequence, when updating packages with `pnpm`, this file will not be processed at all and will soon become outdated.

Can I safely delete `package-lock.json` or will I incur in some problems of sort? Could there be any drawbacks in deleting this file from my project?

*I'm using `npm` only to get the tools and packages needed for my projects (i.e. Gulp), not to publish packages to https://www.npmjs.com/*

Comment: Link update: https://pnpm.io/limitations

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you use pnpm, you can remove `package-lock.json` (and `yarn.lock` if you are switching from Yarn). If you need to preserve some dependencies from your old lockfile, you can run `pnpm import` and pnpm will generate a lockfile using info from `package-lock.json`.

pnpm will create a lockfile of its own. pnpm's lockfile is called `pnpm-lock.yaml`. You should commit this file to the repository.

If you have a CI server, you'll have to use pnpm on the CI server as well, for installing dependencies. [Here are some instructions how to do that](https://pnpm.io/continuous-integration).

Comment: pnpm import bit was amazing to know! thanks.